# Does $\int (x^{dx}-1)$ make sense?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

I came across the YouTube video ["I Computed An Integral That Breaks Math"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVF2nZ0WOY4) by BriTheMathGuy, where the problem is computing

> $$\label{eq_1}\tag{1}\int (x^{dx}-1)$$

And basically to solve this integral we use a little trick writing the argument of $\eqref{eq_1}$ like
$$\label{eq_2}\tag{2}\color{red}{\frac{x^{dx}-1}{dx}}\cdot dx$$
The red part of $\eqref{eq_2}$ could be interpreted as
$$\label{eq_3}\tag{3}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^h-1}{h} = \log (x)$$
And then we can compute the integral of
$$\eqref{eq_1} = \int \log(x)dx = x\log(x) - x + c$$

---

Is this possible, does $\eqref{eq_1}$ even makes sense to write an integral with $dx$ in that unusual position, or is a glamour social media trick? What disturbs me about $\eqref{eq_2}$ is that even tough we can think of $dx$ as an infinitesimal quantity, deeply it isn't, it is a differential. Has someone some thoughts on this or is just a waste of time? Thank you so much.

Comment: I would have demanded to have a definition of $x^{dx}$ given before I would continue any further. But that’s probably why people say I’m grumpy.

Comment: @Arkady you're right... I do not think about that. It does exist?

Comment: Yes, as someone comments on the site, there are formal manipulations in advanced mathematics that seem like this (Chern character, etc.), but they are written in a way that it's clear that one integrates the $n$-form part of a Taylor expansion over an $n$-manifold. And they are written with even-degree differential forms (like curvature) so that wedge product is commutative. I realize this is all too fancy for this post ...

Comment: @TedShifrin would you like to share some links to the topic you are suggesting? Or is hardcore math that is best left to sleep...

Comment: I don't know any instances of this notation/concept that are not pretty advanced. For starters, one has to know about integration of differential forms. However, you might get away with interpreting this using "infinitesimals" in *non-standard analysis* (although I don't remember seeing such expression there).  The standard text on that is by Robinson; there's also a book by Henle and Kleinberg.  You might also look at [this survey article](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/InfinitesimalsHenle.pdf) by Henle.

Comment: Although I wouldn't say it is impossible to make the expression $\int(x^{\mathrm{d}x}-1)$ sensible, I don't see a good reason to do this. The beauty of differentials lies in their power of linearizing complicated objects. So, when a mathematician want to think of a quantity like $x^{\mathrm{d}x}-1$, he/she knows that it is equivalent to $\log x\,\mathrm{d}x$ and will use it in the first place. Another reason is that, when we begin to regard $\mathrm{d}x$ as a standalone object, like a differential form or measure, it becomes even harder to justify operations like this.

Comment: If you really want to give a sense to an expression like $\int x^{\mathrm{d}x}$, it can be interpreted as a *product integral* (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605603/does-the-formula-lim-delta-x-rightarrow-0-sqrt-delta-x-fracfx-delta/4605755#4605755 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral), which can be seen as the inverse operation of the *geometric derivative*, which itself measures how a function varies "multiplicatively". But the manipulations in the video you linked are nonsensical abuses of notation.

Answer (score 2):

You could interpret $\int_{a}^{b}(x^{dx} - 1)$ naturally as a limit of sums $\sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}(\xi_i^{x_{i + 1} - x_i} - 1)$ where $a = x_1 < \dots < x_N = b$ is a partition of $[a, b]$, $\xi_i \in [x_i, x_{i + 1}]$, and the limit is taken as $\max_{1 \leq i \leq N - 1}(x_{i + 1} - x_i) \to 0$. You could probably recover the result you found rigorously. A similar notation arises in survival analysis for the relation of the survival function to the hazard function.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah I should just call them sums; they definitely aren't Riemann sums.

Comment: OK, this seems like a good start. Is there a reasonable way to proceed to evaluate that limit?

Comment: @TedShifrin Probably write it as $\sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}\frac{\xi_i^{\Delta x_i} - 1}{\Delta x_i}\Delta x_i$ and estimate $$|\int_{a}^{b}\log(x)\,dx - \sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}\frac{\xi_i^{\Delta x_i} - 1}{\Delta x_i}\Delta x_i|.$$

Comment: OK, you obviously need to invoke the MVT. (Oh, your sums need to start at $i=0$.)

Comment: @Kakashi sensei, The absolute value you've written above should be numerically approximated or we can use some convergence results in your opinion?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt My opinion is that this definition combined with your proof can easily be turned into a rigorous proof that $\int_{a}^{b} (x^{dx} - 1) = \int_{a}^{b}\log(x)\,dx$ for $b > a > 0$: Using the MVT as Ted Shifrin suggests turns the sum into a Riemann sum for $\log(x)$, which we already know converges to the integral of $\log(x)$.