Why does this simplify to $\exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$
I was messing with the equation:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}\right)^\frac{1}{h}$$
And found that it is equal to:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}e^{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h\cdot f(x)}}$$
I do not know if that is true for all functions but can someone prove it to me and redirect me to anything that has more information on these equations? I am assuming that f(x) is differentiable.

To be honest I don't really remember but I graphed both for many different functions and they were the same every time. Proving that they are not the same would help too.

Do you assume any regularity properties on $f$?

First of all, if $x\to0,$ it doesn't converge to anything with $x$ in it. Are you sure you don't mean $h\to0?$

I mean, if $f$ is continuous and $f(0)\neq0,$ then this limit, as written, is $(f(h)/f(0))^h,$

You're so right! My bad I'll fix that.

Note that you "rediscover" the definition of the so-callwd multiplicative derivative (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925361/multiplicative-derivative).

If the function is differentiable at $x$ then it's true. Just use the definition of derivative, continuity of the exponential function and the chain rule.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}\right)^\frac{1}{h}
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \exp\left(\frac{\log(f(x+h)) - \log(f(x))}{h}\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(f(x+h)) - \log(f(x))}{h}\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\log(f(x))'\right)\\
&= \exp\left(f'(x)/f(x)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
For the other expression:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0} \exp\left(\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h f(x)}\right)
&= \exp\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h }\right) \\
&= \exp\left(f'(x)/f(x)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
By the way, the quantity $f'/f$ is known as the Logarithmic derivative.1

Thanks! as far as I can tell everything is correct. Also I'm assuming f(x) is differentiable.
